# How to implement Caesar cipher?

Tags: java

I am writing a code to decipher a message. For this you input a string and it outputs it in the following way b becomes a, c becomes b and so on. Also for numbers 2 becomes 1, 3 becomes 2.

Comment: Basically you are implementing the Caesar cipher, I would say forget about issue you are getting and check whether it is an efficient implementation, check its run time performance or asymptotic complexity, and its not in good shape ..

Comment: I was looking for toLowerCase and passed right by it I don't know how many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`String.replace(char,char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) replaces **all** the occurrences of the given character with the new character.

So, for example, suppose you have a string like "talk to the tailor", and you ran `replace('t','w')` on it, you get "walk wo whe wailor".

But this means that once you get to the letters you have already replaced, you will be replacing them again - going back another letter.

You should not use `replace` for this. The best thing to do would probably be to use a `StringBuilder` and just append each letter to it after you decipher it.

---

Also note that it's very wasteful to go through the entire alphabet just to find the letter. First, there is already such a method, called `indexOf` in the `String` class. Second, for the English alphabet and digits, the character unicode values are consecutive. This means that you can get to `a` from `b` by simply substracting one:

```
char ch = 'b';
ch = (char)(ch - 1);
```

This will give you `a` in `ch`. So all you need to do is make sure that the character is in the given range, and then subtract 1 from it.

Comment: You shouldn't . You should separate your source and target strings. So start with an empty `StringBuilder` and append the characters to it. If a character is not a letter or a digit, append it as is. If it is, decipher and append.